# Count function in Zabbix's Trigger condition

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to create a trigger that can count the amount of value 1 that appears 3 times from zabbix's item in 30 seconds. My trigger condition is:

```
{myserver:service.myservice.count(30)}> 3
```

I'm not sure if this condition is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition counts the number of values in 30 seconds.

...`.count(30,1)` counts the number of values 1 in 30 seconds.

More examples are given in: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions